# Binding to a Collection of Checkboxes

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm trying to do some XAML binding for the Windows Phone (targeting WP7.1) and I have a collection of checkboxes that I want to display.  I want to put them inside the `WrapPanel`

What control(s) would I use to bind to a collection of checkboxes?  I don't see an ItemSource for the `WrapPanel`.  So I'm not sure what I would use.

```
   <ListBox Height="auto" Name="lbAssignments" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Text="{Binding Title}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,10" FontSize="26.667" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="{Binding Title}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,10" FontSize="26.667" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Height="400" Width="400">
                        <!--collection of checkboxes-->
                    </toolkit:WrapPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Does your DataList represent the collection of boolean values or does each item in DataList contain a collection of bools?

Comment: As @Phil suggested, please show us the underlying model you want to display.

Comment: Right now I just want something VERY Simple to work with.  I have a simple List<string> that has text in it.  How would I display these with checkboxes?

Comment: Is this something where an ItemsControl with Checkbox as its ItemTemplate would remedy it? Or is it more complicated than I'm seeing?

Comment: It might be.  I really want it simple right now.  I've never done it so any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding to a collection of UI controls is not exactly the thing you'd want to do. Instead, I would recommend binding to a collection. For many reasons - performance, memory allocation and general maintenance/flexibility.

Since you mentioned that you have a `List<string>`, you can just bind it to a `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However, you can still proceed with biding an element to a collection of other elements, given that appropriate support exists. You could use an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myPage, Path=SomeCollection}">

</ItemsControl>
```

Here, `SomeCollection` might as well be `ObservableCollection<CheckBox>`.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try it out this weekend!  I appreciate the input and the example code.